# I need to take all the lines at once and work with them, but I get line-by-line reception

Tags: java

when there is a reading of lines and work with them continues line by line

I need to accept multi-line input first and only then to work the code

```
public class OrderRestaurant {
 
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String line = null;
    
    TreeMap<String, LinkedList<Integer>> orderMap = new TreeMap<String, LinkedList<Integer>>();
      Set<Integer> tableSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] orders = line.split(",");
    
        for (int i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
            
            tableSet.add(Integer.parseInt(orders[1]));  
        }
            
            if (!(orderMap.containsKey(orders[2]))) {
                LinkedList<Integer> numbersTables = new LinkedList<>();
                numbersTables.add(Integer.parseInt(orders[1]));
            
                orderMap.put(orders[2], numbersTables);
            } else {
                orderMap.get(orders[2]).addLast(Integer.parseInt(orders[1]));
            }
         
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder("Table");
        
        Set<String>keysOrderMapSet=orderMap.keySet();
        for (String keyString : keysOrderMapSet) {
            sBuilder.append(',').append(keyString);
        }
        
         for(Integer key : tableSet){
             sBuilder.append("\n").append(key);
            
             for(Map.Entry<String, LinkedList<Integer>> entry : orderMap.entrySet())
             {
                 LinkedList<Integer> numbersOrder = entry.getValue();
                 int counterOrder = 0;
                 
                 for (int i = 0; i < numbersOrder.size(); i++) {
                     if(numbersOrder.get(i)==key) {
                         counterOrder++;
                     }
                   }
                 sBuilder.append(',').append(counterOrder);
                 }
         }
          System.out.println(sBuilder.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

all input is green, further you can see that the output after the program runs is formed in parts and only at the end is displayed in its entirety.

[image: img]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Perhaps you should read from a file.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from the question is that you want to read all lines from the console first then need to do any operation or work and after that, you want to print the result for each line on the console. If that is the case then you need to create an intermediate array or list to hold the data of each line. Please refer below steps:

1. Create an empty list as `readLineByLineString` that holds your input line by line.
2. Read line from the console using `Scanner` or `BufferedReader`.
3. Add that line to the list by `readLineByLineString.add(line);`

   - Read all the lines and add to the list until all test cases satisfy or required conditions.
4. Now you have all your data line by line in an intermediate list i.e. `readLineByLineString`, just do the required operation.
5. `Print` your result after each operation.
6. End

Comment: The problem is that my code does intermediate output every time I add lines. I need to accept a few lines and do not do the output line by line, but immediately output the processed table result

Comment: As Ashish says in his answer, you must modify your code to process the inputs after the user has entered multiple. His example modified workflow would be what you would implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can read for example 1024 bytes at a time.

```
char[] myBuffer = new char[512];
int bytesRead = 0;
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(reader));
while ((bytesRead = in.read(myBuffer,0,1024)) != -1)
{ ...  }
```